# Agregar filas a tabla si perder tag helper asp-items

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, mvc

Estoy agregando nuevas filas a mi vista con codigo js de esta forma:

```
function insertarFila() {
    const tblDatos = document.getElementById('data-table').insertRow(2);
    const col1 = tblDatos.insertCell(0);
    const col2 = tblDatos.insertCell(1);

    col1.innerHTML = '<button onclick="eliminarFila()" class="bi bi-trash btn btn-outline-danger"></button>';
    col2.innerHTML = '<select asp-items="Model.Paises" class="form-select"></select>';
}
```

Vista:

```
<table id="data-table" class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col"></th>
                            <th scope="col">Departamento</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <select id="paisSlt" asp-items="Model.Paises" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" onchange="ShowSelected()">
                                    
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="2" class="text-center">
                                <a onclick="insertarFila()" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Añadir fila</a>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
```

Con asp-items obtengo la lista que necesito de mi IEnumerable, el problema que tengo es que al añadir una nueva fila con mi function de js, no funciona el asp-items y los select me aparecen vacíos.

Agradecería de antemano cualquier ayuda.